# django access field across multiple models

Tags: python, django, foreign-key-relationship, html

I am using the following models in my django application and want to query across multiple fields. I looked around different places but couldnt find out what i exactly need.

```
class Attempt(models.Model, object):
    '''Creates an Attempt Entity which is a subclass of models.Model class'''
    attemptID_f = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    questionID_f = models.ForeignKey(Question, verbose_name="Question", null=False)
    userID_f = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name="User ID", null=False)
    solution_f = models.TextField("Solution uploaded by the User", null=False)
    errorReportID_f = models.ForeignKey(ErrorReport,verbose_name="Error Report for the Solution", null=True)
    status_f = models.BooleanField("Status of attempt - true = right, false = wrong", blank=True, default=False)
    timeOfSubmission_f = models.DateTimeField("Time of Submission", null=False)
    compilerVersion_f = models.ForeignKey(CompilerVersion, verbose_name = "Compiler version of the Attempt",null=False)

class Question(models.Model, object):
    '''Creates the entity question 
    which is a subclass of models.Model'''
    questionID_f = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    questionText_f = models.TextField("Problem Statement", null=False)
    questionTitle_f = models.CharField("Problem Title", max_length = 50, null = False) 
    level_f = models.ForeignKey(Level, verbose_name="Question Level", null=False)
    type_f = models.ForeignKey(Type, verbose_name="Type of Question", null=False)
    timeLimit_f = models.FloatField("Time Limit for Question",null=False)

class Type(models.Model):
    '''Creates the entity Type which is a subclass of models.Model class'''
    typeID_f = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    typeName_f = models.CharField("Type Name" , max_length = 30 , null = False)

typesm = Attempt.objects.filter(userID_f = request.user).values('attempt__questionID_f__type_f__typeID_f')
```

Is `attempt__questionID_f__type_f__typeID_f` a valid arguement if I want to reference the `typeID_f` field of type MODEL, which is referenced by `type_f` field of Question Model, which is referenced by `questionID_f` field of Attempt Model ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Pankaj.

Comment: Have you tried it? Is there a problem with what you have tried?

Comment: What's the point of inheriting from `models.Model, object`? A mixin is only useful if it adds something, which `object` can't do by definition.

Comment: I really hope that "_f" is in your company's style guide...

Comment: It does not work, I tried it. I import object because I wanted to create "properties". And yes "_f" is our style

Comment: Also I hope that the `attempt = ...` line is not actually on the module level in your real code.

Comment: @Panx: `models.Model` and pretty much all other classes already are sub-classes of `object`. So what you are doing is completely redundant (well, *new style* classes to be more specific, but that should be true for any Django class: http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#new-style-and-classic-classes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be:

```
typesm = Attempt.objects.filter(userID_f = request.user).values('questionID_f__type_f__typeID_f')
```

I'm not sure why you put the `attempt__` prefix there when you are querying the `Attempt` model.

See: [Lookups that span relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships)

Answer (score 0):

I think that if you are using filter then something similar to what you wrote should work fine

```
Attempt.objects.filter(questionID_f__type_f__typeID_f=42)
```

To find all `Attempt` objects with Type 42.

If you have an Attempt instance `attempt` then you want to write

```
if attempt.questionID_f.type_f.typeID_f == 42:
    print "Answer found!"
```

Some style points:

- django makes an `AutoField` called `id` by default
- no need to inherit from `object`
- wow those `_f`s are ugly! You can rename the column name in the db if you want with the [db_column](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.db_column) option if you have some SQL style to fit into
- no need to say `which is a subclass of models.Model` in your help - it says exactly that in the code and all of the python documentation systems understand that

Comment: Can i use the same thing as a string arguement to the values () function call ?